# Event after a div has finished animating?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make a function run after a certain element has finished animating? It's a slide-down like animation, the element is hidden and when something is clicked, it will become visible by sliding its contents down (+height).

I have no control over the animation function on that element, so I can't use the callback option from the $.animate function...

Right now I have something like

```
$('.trigger').click(function(){  // <-- "trigger" will make the element animate 
  setTimeout(myfunction, 500);
});
```

which works but I don't like it, feels hacky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're using jQuery 1.5+ you could use the jQuery `promise()` method : http://jsfiddle.net/rGBk7/

e.g.

```
/* do animation */
$("div").animate({ 'marginLeft' : '300px' }, 1000);

/* attach a promise to animated element/s */    
$("div").promise().done(function() {
    alert("animation end");
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: this runs as soon as the page loads. The problem is that my animation runs on user intervention (click on a different element)

Comment: something like that, but like I said, I have no control over the animation function :( So it should be: http://jsfiddle.net/rGBk7/20/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fcalderan/rGBk7/24/ this only need to bind another handler after

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
$("div").queue(function(){
    your_function();
});
```

It will be executed after the animation queue is complete